# How to specify series color dynamically for 3D bar chart in iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am working with 3D bar chart. I want to specify bar color dynamically. If the value is 1-3 display Red. for 3-7 display orange and for 7-10 display green. How can I achieve that in iReport?

Comment: I am facing the same issue..Kindly let me know if it's possible..